# JScript Array with custom array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Consider this, I have a JScript array of arrays.

I want to copy a given index of the array into another array using the same index.

So for example:

MyArray = {[0] = Array, [1] = Array, [2] = Array}

I want to copy the 3rd index [2] into another array, such that the first index is not '0' but '2'.

Giving Me:

MyNextArray[2] = {Array}

Apologies for the pseudo code.

Can I make the copy or do I have to first initialize the array and then set a custom index?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not very clear, you should rephrase a little

Answer (score 0):

```
MyArray = {[0] = Array, [1] = Array, [2] = Array}
var MyNewArray = sortRay(MyArray, 2);

function sortRay(Ray, firstNr){
    MyNextArray =  new Array();
    MyNextArray[0] =  Ray[firstNr];
    for(var i = 0, j = 1; i <= Ray.length, i++){
        if(i == firstNr){i++, j = 0;}
        MyNextArray[i+j] = MyArray[i];
    }
    return MyNextArray;
}
```

shld work